# Median filter library array dimension

Tags: c++

I want to use a median filter to smooth an image. I have found the library located here: 
http://librow.com/articles/article-1
My question relies if the algorithm expects a one or two dimensional array (from what I have understood median filter reads the values in "windows" of 3x3 in the current algorithm and then picks the median of them and replaces all the pixels in the window with it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below function

```
void _medianfilter(const element* signal, element* result, int N)
```

requires a one dimensional array as input and returns the smoothed result in again an one dimensional array.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. I was refering to this function: void _medianfilter(const element* image, element* result, int N, int M). (I know it seems obvious that it uses two dimensions but in the code it doesn't seem anywhere to use two dimension array).

Comment: two dimensional arrays can be visualized as one dimensional array stored either in row major order or column major order